# Mysql: MyIsam or InnoDB when UUID will be used as PK

Tags: mysql, innodb, uuid, myisam

I am working on a project where I need to use a UUID (16bit) as unique identifier in the database (MySQL). The database has a lot of tables with relations. I have the following questions about using a UUID as PK:

1. Should I index the unique identifier as PK / FK or is it not necessary?
   If I index it, the index size will increase, but it is really needed?

Enclose an example where i have to use uuid: 
Table user with one unique identifier (oid) and foreign key (language).

CREATE TABLE user (
oid binary(16) NOT NULL,
username varchar(80) ,
f_language_oid binary(16) NOT NULL,
**PRIMARY KEY** (oid),
**KEY** f_language_oid (f_language_oid),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

Is it helpful / necessary to define "oid" as PRIMARY_KEY and language as FOREIGN_KEY or would it be bette, if i only create the table without key definitions?

I have read in this article ([here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2002/can-i-have-create-an-innodb-table-without-a-pk-if-so-would-a-secondary-index-b)) that innodb will generate automatically an 6bit integer als primary key (hidden). In this case, it would be better to use the 6bit internal pk than the 16bit binary key?

2. If no index is required, should I use MyISAM or InnoDB?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

With MySQL it's often advantageous to use a regular `INT` as your primary key and have a UUID as a secondary `UNIQUE` index. This is mostly because I believe MySQL uses the primary key as a row identifier in all secondary indexes, and having large values here can lead to vastly bigger index sizes. Do some testing at scale to see if this impacts you.

The one reason to use a UUID as a primary key would be if you're trying to spread data across multiple independent databases and want to avoid primary key conflicts. UUID is a great way to do this.

In either case, you'll probably want to express the UUID as text so it's human readable and it's possible to do manipulate data easily. It's difficult to paste in binary data into your query, for example, must to do a simple `UPDATE` query. It will also ensure that you can export to or import from JSON without a whole lot of conversion overhead.

As for MyISAM vs. InnoDB, it's really highly ill-advised to use the old MyISAM database in a production environment where data integrity and uptime are important. That engine can suffer catastrophic data loss if the database becomes corrupted, something as simple as an unanticipated reboot can cause this, and has trouble recovering. InnoDB is a modern, journaled, transactional database engine that's significantly more resilient and recovers from most sudden failure situations automatically, even database crashes.

One more consideration is evaluating if [PostgreSQL](http://postgresql.org/) is a suitable fit because it has a native UUID column type.

Comment: Thanks for your very fast reply. The explanation about MyIsam and InnoDB is very well. 

I have the following example where i have to use uuid: 
table user with one unique identifier (oid) and foreign key (language)

CREATE TABLE user (
  `oid` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(80) ,
  `f_language_oid` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`oid`),
  KEY `f_language_oid` (`f_language_oid`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

Is it helpful / necessary to define "oid" as PRIMARY_KEY and language as FOREIGN_KEY?